# 403 Forbidden when trying to get creative's image from Linkedin CDN

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get creative's image from Linkedin CDN, assuming having its `imageId` from the REST API.
And I simply followed approach provided in the documentation:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/create-and-manage-creatives

It's written there:

> Note: to construct the complete URL for a creative's image, you'll
>   have to append the `imageId` to `https://media.licdn.com/media`.

And I did exactly so: I took `imageId` from API response (`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{creative_id}` endpoint) and appended it to the url from the docs above. However, I'm getting `403 Forbidden` in response without any body. Also I tried it both with access token in header and without.

**Example:**

creative id: `968867`

imageId: `/p/4/000/170/199/3098bbc.png`,

request:

```
~ wget https://media.licdn.com/media/p/4/000/170/199/3098bbc.png
--2018-07-01 17:00:53--  https://media.licdn.com/media/p/4/000/170/199/3098bbc.png
Resolving media.licdn.com (media.licdn.com)... 23.59.118.49
Connecting to media.licdn.com (media.licdn.com)|23.59.118.49|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2018-07-01 17:00:53 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Should I have any cookie in header to make it work?

Would appreciate any help